# с# mysql, Access denied for user

Tags: c#, mysql

приложение winforms, пытаюсь добавить данные в базу Mysql. в combobox вывел список таблиц, выбираю один из таблиц и пытаюсь добавить данные в эту таблицу выходить такая ошибка authentication to host for user using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user "@'DESKTOP-8BR4U(using password: NO). в mysql давал все привилегий для пользователя. не знаю в чем может быть проблема. помогите разобраться. ниже выложил таблицу user host баз данных. и собственно код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Biling_DSLAM
{
public partial class Openpage : Form
{
    public Openpage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
    
    int id;
    string query;



    private void Openpage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {


        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.102; UserId = admin; Password = 12345");
        con.Open();
        var command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dslam'";



        var adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        con.Close();
    }
    }
   
   
    private DataTable AutoNumberedTable(DataTable SourceTable)

    {
        DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn AutoNumberColumn = new DataColumn
        {
            ColumnName = "id",
            DataType = typeof(int),
            AutoIncrement = true,
            AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
            AutoIncrementStep = 1
        };
        ResultTable.Columns.Add(AutoNumberColumn);
        ResultTable.Merge(SourceTable);
        return ResultTable;
    }

    private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (comboBox1.Items.ToString() == "sats60")
            {
                query = "insert into sta60(id, name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date) Values (null, '" + Nametextbox.Text + "', '" + Surnametextbox.Text + "', '" + phonetextbox.Text + "', '" + logintextbox.Text + "', '" + dslamcomboBox.Text + "', '" + porttextbox.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
               
            }
           
            if (comboBox1.Items.ToString() == "sats70")
            { 
                query = "insert into sta70(id, name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date) Values (null, '" + Nametextbox.Text + "', '" + Surnametextbox.Text + "', '" + phonetextbox.Text + "', '" + logintextbox.Text + "', '" + dslamcomboBox.Text + "', '" + porttextbox.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";

            }
           
               MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            
            con.Open();
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Added!");
                }
                con.Close();

             
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
            con.Close();
        }
       
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        Nametextbox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Surnametextbox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        phonetextbox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        logintextbox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        dslamcomboBox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        porttextbox.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
           DataSetDateTime.Local.ToString();
    }

    private void Exitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подключаетесь как неавторизованный пользователь по умолчанию с логином машины хоста из-за строки `MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();`.

Авторизованное подключение у вас создается только в локальной для метода `Openpage_Load` переменной conn, которая никак не относится к внешней переменной и туда ваша строка подключения не попадает.

Можете убрать локальное определение

```
private void Openpage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.102; UserId = admin; Password = 12345");
    ...
}
```

Но лучше просто создавайте подключение как-то в едином стиле, чтобы не путаться. Можно к примеру подсмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618283/9033215

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ ! вытащил на наружи, теперь появляется другая ошибка : the CommandText property has not been properly initialized

Comment: тоесть как добавлять в конкретную базу данных через combobox добавить данные ? тоесть как добавлять в конкретную базу данных через combobox добавить данные ? if (comboBox1.Items.ToString() == "sats60")
            {
                query = "insert into sta60(id, name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date) Values (null, '" + Nametextbox.Text + "', '" + Surnametextbox.Text + "', '" + phonetextbox.Text + "', '" + logintextbox.Text + "', '" + dslamcomboBox.Text + "', '" + porttextbox.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
               
            }  такой вариант подходит ?

Comment: @Misterjunior, либо вы открыли соединение позже, чем написали команду, либо надо обязательно заполнять поле command.CommandText как вы делаете это в Openpage_Load. Если бы ошибка была в запросе, текст был бы связан с ним.

Comment: не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться , я хочу передать в combobox таблицу и при выборе таблицы добавлять в эту таблицу данные. но почему-то мой код не работает для combobox .

Comment: ` private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.102; Initial Catalog = '" + comboBox1.Text.ToString() + "'; UserId = admin; Password = 12345");
            con.Open();
            DataTable schema = con.GetSchema("Tables");
            con.Close();
        } `

Comment: @Misterjunior, можно либо дополнять исходный вопрос, либо задавать новый. В комментариях сами видите, код не особо читабельный. Ну и не нужно путать схемы и таблицы в схемах. Я собрал тестовый пример, ошибок не получил: https://pastebin.com/kxPFLfg6 Хотя у меня локально конечно своя схема test и таблица в ней product. Initial Catalog для схемы (базы), если она не указана в соединении, то для вставки в таблицу надо так же дополнять запрос схемой `insert into test.product ...`.

Comment: спасибо , я исправил свою ошибку.  вы не могли бы откликнуться на другой мой вопрос ? при вставке запись в базу данных я хочу выбирать таблицу через combobox. вот сам вопрос  по ссылке  [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369287/c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-mysql-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-combobox]